# meteor : generate qr code using steeve:jquery-qrcode

Tags: meteor, qr-code

I have created qrcode using **steeve:jquery-qrcode** package but now I have problem to display qrcode image (text) base on _id collection. I want the **_id** data as qrcode image and when scann the result is **_id** data. please someone help me.

This my code:
//html

```
`<template name="profile">
<div class="container-fluid">
Username: {{kategori}}<br />
{{#if profil}}
Profile name: {{kategori}}
{{/if}}
  <div class="qrblock" id="qrblock"  src="/{{. }}"> </div>

<a id="downloadImgLink" onclick="$('#downloadImgLink').attr('href', $('#qrblock canvas')[0].toDataURL());" download="MyImage.png" href="#" target="_blank">Download Drawing</a>
</div>
</template>`
```

//js

```
`Template.profile.helpers({
profil: function(){
return Profil.find({});
}
});
Template.profile.onRendered(function (event) {
 this. $('.container').qrcode({itemSelector: '.qrblock'});
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the div you've referenced with your jquery selector `$('.container').qrcode({itemSelector: '.qrblock'});`

In your html you need to add

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Also in the .qrcode() you should write what you want to receive on the qr code reader side with "text" e.g. `.qrcode({ text: "http://stackoverflow.com"})`

Comment: But I want qrcode generate as auto when user click the data. Can u understand what I mean?

Comment: then the same applies but put the $('.container').qrcode({ text: "http://stackoverflow.com" }); in the onClink event and pass the value of "text" as a js variable e.g. {text: textVar}